# Password reset not working in Laravel 5.1 LTS

Tags: php, laravel

I'm working with Laravel 5.1 LTS (previously upgraded from 4 following the instructions) and tried to implement password reminders. In my routes I have

```
Route::controllers([
     'auth' => '\App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController',
    'password' => '\App\Http\Controllers\Auth\PasswordController',
]);
```

However when I go to http://localhost/password/reset I get the following:

```
NotFoundHttpException in ResetsPasswords.php line 67:
```

The route password/reset exists:

```
| GET|HEAD                       | password/reset/{one?}/{two?}/{three?}/{four?}/{five?}  |                             | \App\Http\Controllers\Auth\PasswordController@getReset
```

Any ideas? Why would it need a token? I would expect for just the reset form to be displayed. If it does require a token, what token should I pass?

If I pass a random string e.g. password/reset/123123123 I get the following error

```
Trying to get property of non-object (View: 
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/myProject/resources/views/layout.blade.php)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are a little off on the flow of the password reset functionality.

The process of resetting your password involves you first requesting a reset token to your email address, this then generates a token in the `passwords_reset` table and emails this to the user in an email.

They then visit the `password/reset` url with the token; i.e `http://localhost/password/reset/123tokenExample123`.

The `password/reset` url requires a token to be passed to it, [otherwise you get the error](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.1/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/ResetsPasswords.php#L64) you have found if you don't.

First go to `http://localhost/password/email` to request the token and create it, then visit `http://localhost/password/reset/` and enter the token created at the end to reset that users password.

Comment: I might have been confused by a Laravel 5.2 tutorial that does password resets in a slightly different way.